# When to use raw binary and when base64?

Tags: web-services, http, base64, network-protocols

I want to develop a service which receives files from users. At first, I was willing to implement uploads using raw binary in order to save time (base64 increases file size by about 33%), but reading about base64 it seems to be very useful if you don't want problems uploading files.

The question is what are the downsides of implementing raw binary uploads? And in which cases it makes sense? In this case I will develop client and server so I will have control over these two, but what about routers or network, can they corrupt data if not in base64?

I'm trying to investigate what dropbox or google drive do and why, but I can't find an article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't have any problems using raw binary for file uploads.  All Internet Protocol networking hardware is required to be [8 bit clean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-bit_clean) - that is to transmit all 8 bits of every byte/octet.

If you choose to use the TCP protocol, it guarantees reliable transmission of octets (bytes).  Encoding using base64 would be a waste of time and bandwidth.